# Convert registry entry from REG_SZ to REG_DWORD?

Tags: c#, registry

I've inherited an application with registry entries like "AutoLogOff" (and many similar items) as a REG_SZ type but it only has values of "0" or "1". It would be more logical for this to be numerical (ie. a DWORD). Is there a simple way to convert an existing REG_SZ entry to a REG_DWORD (change type)?

I suppose I could detect "upgrade from old version", extract the REG_SZ value and delete the existing registry key, then re-create the registry key with the same name but as a REG_DWORD type...but it seems like there might be an easier way. Using C# here, though it is the principle I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "easy way", it requires deleting the value and adding it back.

This is not a fantastic idea, if the user ever restores an older version of the app for whatever reason (it does happen a lot more often than you might think) then the old version is very likely to misbehave, not limited to a hard crash.  So do *not* try to change the type, simply use a value with another name.  Like "AutoLogOff2".  Eventually machines with the old name will disappear.  The effort of creating the new value is otherwise the same.  Yuck factor is high.

Comment: OK, that's reasonable. I see what you mean about a possible downgrade. If the entry is changed to a DWORD (by deleting then re-creating), when the older application is installed, it will try to read "AutoLogOff" as a REG_SZ...which the older application may or may not handle elegantly!